# Generate all possible sequence of altrenate digits and alphabets

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, combinations, permutation

I want to generate all possible sequence of alternative digit and numbers. For example

5j1c6l2d4p9a9h9q

6d5m7w4c8h7z4s0i

3z0v5w1f3r6b2b1z

NumberSmallletterNumberSmallletter
NumberSmallletterNumberSmallletter
NumberSmallletterNumberSmallletter
NumberSmallletterNumberSmallletter

I can do it by using 16 loop But it will take 30+ hours (rough idea). Is there any efficient way. I hope there will be in python.

Comment: Look into `itertools`, you could use `product` to generate all of these. It will still take a while to get through them, though...

Comment: @jonrsharpe in fact I am new I am trying form last 3 days. I thought to get help from here.

Comment: No, there's no efficient way to generate 20882706457600000000 sequences.  On the bright side, it's hard to think of a reason you'd need to.

Comment: I'm giving you help, I'm telling you to look at itertools.product. You shouldn't expect to get it written for you. As @DSM points out, though, although that would let you *write* it more neatly the algorithmic complexity is still pretty bad.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know I have to do it by myself. I am also looking into it. Thank you for your reply :)

Comment: What you want is impossible. First off, there are infinitely many sequences of alternating digits and letters. And even if you limit the length, this is a combinatorial problem, and there is a *reason* why we characterize the growth rate of combinatorial problems by the phrase "combinatorial **explosion**". For example, for a sequence of length 16, there are 20882706457600000000 sequences. Even if you had a 10GHz CPU with 100 cores and could generate one sequence per CPU cycle on each core in parallel, it would take you 8 months.

Comment: @ForceBru Ohhh Thank you for your reply

Comment: @StefanPochmann, well, if just allocating a constant takes 0.01 seconds, then _generating_ something must take much longer.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, this is what `timeit.timeit("'1234567890123456'")` returns when run from the interpreter.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, super weird, indeed! With such timings Python should've been super slow, but this is what `timeit.timeit` says, so... The problem is, I always thought it does the division automatically. Okay, `%timeit '1234567890123456'` in IPython says 11 nanoseconds, which looks way better. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: @StefanPochmann, yep, I definitely messed up there, sorry about that. Still, that's gonna be a huge number. 229709771033.59998 seconds, or 7284.049 years, which is still a lot. Also, IPython's `%timeit` _does_ the division automatically, which is convenient, but `timeit.timeit` doesn't, which causes the confusion.

Comment: @ForceBru WolframAlpha [roughly agrees :-)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=20882706457600000000+*+0.01112546799959091%2F10%5E6+seconds+in+years).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is my answer what you had in mind... I have only used `itertools.product` a couple of times and I think it's right...

Comment: Write a generator for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`itertools.product`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate all of the `16` long cases:

```
import string, itertools
i = itertools.product(string.digits, string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=8)
j = (''.join(p) for p in i)
```

As `i` is an iterator of `tuples`, we need to convert these all to `strings` (so they are in the format that you want). This is relatively straight forward to do as we can just pass each `tuple` into a `generator` and `join` the elements together into one `string`.

---

We can see that the iterator (`j`) is working by calling `next()`  on it a couple of times:

```
>>> next(j)
'0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a'
>>> next(j)
'0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0b'
>>> next(j)
'0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0c'
>>> next(j)
'0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0d'
>>> next(j)
'0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0e'
>>> next(j)
'0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0f'
>>> next(j)
'0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0g'
```

Comment: I'd have used string.digits but otherwise this is pretty much exactly what I had in mind, yes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, I was thinking that too, but `string.digits` includes the `0` which I don't think is desired... I guess you could do: `string.digits[1:]`

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh ha my bad!

Comment: @JoeIddon Thank you so much that is exactly what I was trying to achieve.   
 jonrsharpe That's 0 not o. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "efficient" way to do this. There are `2.8242954e+19` different possible combonations, or `28,242,954,000,000,000,000`. If each combination is 16 characters long, storing this all in a raw text file would take up `451,887,264,000` gigabytes, `441,296,156.25` terabytes, `430,953.2775878906` petabytes, or `420.8528101444` exabytes. The largest hard drive available to the average consumer is 16TB (Samsung PM1633a). They cost 12 thousand US dollars. This puts the total cost of storing all of this data to 330,972,117,600 US dollars (3677.46797 times Bill Gates' net worth). Even ignoring the amount of space all of these drives would take up, and ignoring the cost of the hardware you would need to connect them to, and assuming that they could all be running at highest performance all together in a lossless RAID array, this would make the write speed 330,972,118 gigabytes a second. Sounds like a lot, doesn't it? Even with that write speed, the file would take 22 minutes to write, assuming that there were no bottlenecks from CPU power, RAM speed, or the RAID controller itself.

Sources - a calculator.

Comment: So basically, "you can't store all the numbers at once". Maybe an alternative suggestion? A generator expression maybe?

Comment: @tobias_k good point, using a generator expression would be a good idea. Writing a function or something that would return something at a specific index. OP, do you want me to explain how to write this for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
n = 5
ans = [0 for i in range(26)]
all = ['a','b','A','Z','0','1']
def rec(pos, prev):
    if (pos==n) :
        for i in range(n):
            sys.stdout.write(str(ans[i]))
            sys.stdout.flush()
        print ""
        return

    for i in all:
        if(i != prev):
            ans[pos] = i
            rec(pos+1, i)
    return
for i in all:
    ans[0] = i;
    rec(1, i)
```

The basic idea is [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking). It is too slow. But code is short. You can modify your characters in 'all' and length of the sequences n.
If you don't clear about the code then try to simulate it with some cases.